# iOS Uninstall view for wCompact hAny but retain it for other size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, landscape, size-classes

I would like to show a label at the bottom of a view, but there isn't enough room in compact width mode (iPhone portrait mode).

I installed the label in wAny hAny and uninstalled it for wCompact hAny.  It doesn't show in iPhone portrait mode as I intended. However, I was expecting it to appear when I rotated an iPhone to landscape in the simulator.  It did not appear.

How should I accomplish this?

Thanks

Thank you Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All iPhones except for the 6+ have Compact width even in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a label in Landscape only :

Uninstall the label for wAny hAny and install it for **wAny hCompact** only. 
As explained in [Adaptative and Layout documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html), compact height is only used for iPhone 4, 5, 6 and 6+ in landscape orientation.